Factoring room temperature into analysis of skin conductance?
If I want to compare skin conductance between three different groups (they differ between different types of VR exposure) with an RM anova (with the factor time), and also have the room temperature of each experimental session, how could I factor the temperature into my analysis?
I did some previous research, but the literature only suggests to keep temperature constant, which was not possible due to measurements taking place throughout the whole year and this summer being especially hot.
Should I simply include the room temperature as a covariate?
Many thanks,
Mark

Welcome. Are there repeated measurements (each subject is measured with different VRs, or repeatedly with the same VR over time etc.), or is every participant recorded just once?
